# Table td spacing not even

Tags: html, html-table

Can anyone think of a reason why the spacing between the links in the top navigation bar isn't even:

http://ws2699-2868.staging.nitrosell.com/store/

It's a table set to the full page width and the text centred but the text links on the left have less space around them then those on the right!

I don't have control over the HTML output, if I did I wouldn't be using tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your table .class='tab-table' try to set the width to auto right now your table is set to 980px and it will spread out the columns to meet that width. You will then need to add padding to the columns to get the even spacing but at least the spacing will be consistent. For the spacing i would just add

```
.tab-middle { 
    padding: 0 5px 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's crazy that table data isn't automatically spaced evenly!

Comment: It seems rather odd to me that by default the padding is not computed to be the same in every cell. In what cases would you want evenly spaced cells to have different amounts of padding, such that that behavior is the default? Either way, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make each cell a particular width if you want them to all be the same size. So if you take 980 / 9 = 108.88px. You may also have to adjust for padding/margins, but thats the idea.

```
.tab-table td {
    width: 108.88px;
}
```